# How to escape commas in environment-variables mapped to lists in Spring configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, docker

This question is a duplicate of the following question, which is over 5 years old and hasn't received an accepted answer.

[How to escape "," (comma) in Spring String to array or List conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691792/how-to-escape-comma-in-spring-string-to-array-or-list-conversion)

I have a docker-contained spring-application which is customisable via environment variables.

Spring will pick up the environment variables and map them to the fields in configuration classes.

One such field is a `List<String>`. It correctly splits my environment variable on the comma character. The issue comes when one of my fields contains a comma.

I tried the following:

```
-e LIST1='"1","2a,2b","3"'
-e LIST2="'1','2a,2b','3'"
-e LIST3="1,2a\,2b,3"
-e LIST4="1,2a\\,2b,3"
-e LIST5='1,2a\,2b,3'
-e LIST6='1,2a\\,2b,3'
```

In every scenario, spring simply does a string split over the comma character, resulting in some of my values containing characters such as `\`, `'`, `"`.

Comment: Would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** escape comma for list in spring boot , I'm afraid you will have to think of alternative way to load those environment variables

Comment: There's no way there's no workaround